# Android: XML resources (values)

Tags: android, xml

I must make a few translations for my app.
But when I compile my app, console write:

```
[2012-11-24 15:31:43 - com.ddm.ctimer.MainForm] W/ResourceType( 4892): Bad XML block: header size 297 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-11-24 15:31:43 - com.ddm.ctimer.MainForm] C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\NewTimer\NewTimer\res\values-fr\strings.xml:6: error: Found text "
[2012-11-24 15:31:43 - com.ddm.ctimer.MainForm] В В В В  " where item tag is expected
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">CTimer</string>
<!--RUS strings-->
    <!--MainForm-->
    <string name="main_form_sec">Chronomètre</string>
     <string name="main_form_tim"> Minuterie </string>
     <string name="main_form_set"> Paramètres </string>
<string name="main_form_bg">#000000</string>

    <!--Menu-->
    <string name="menu_about">À propos du programme</string>
    <string name="menu_buy">Supprimer les annonces</string>
    <!--Preferences(Settings)-->
```

Comment: please, show the first 10 lines of your `/values-fr/strings.xml`?

Comment: please, add them to your question, properly formatted, because I cannot understand where your lines start and end

Comment: try to add colors on a separated file named `values/colors.xml`  : 
`<color name="background_main_form">#000000</color>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have a problem with the encoding, resource files are supposed to be encoded in UTF-8.

Please, try to replace **"Chronomètre"** with something in plain English and see if your error disappears or moves to the next "translated" line.

Comment: after you change files, please, try a clean build of the project and see if the error goes away

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use colors.xml for colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="main_form_bg">#000000</color>
</resources>
```